# why laravel shows random results for downloading files?

Tags: database, laravel, model-view-controller

At first I want to show `FileDownload` statics and numbers to User...so I made a Model named `FileDownload`:

```
 protected $guarded = ['id'];
 protected $dates = [
    'download_date'
  ];
 public $timestamps = false;
```

then I write the code below for Model `File.php` :

```
 public function updateDownloadCounts() {

    $isDownloadExistForToday = FileDownload::where('file_id',$this->file_id)->
    whereDate('download_date',Carbon::today())->first();
    if($isDownloadExistForToday && $isDownloadExistForToday instanceof FileDownload)
    {
        $isDownloadExistForToday->increment('download_count');
    }else{
        FileDownload::create([
            'file_id' => $this->file_id,
            'download_count' => 1,
            'download_date' => Carbon::now()
        ]);
    }

}
```

And it is my `FileController` using download files:

```
 public function download(Request $request, int $file_id)
{
    $current_user = Auth::user();
    if (!\App\Utility\File::user_can_download($current_user->id)) {
        return view('frontend.files.access');
    }
    $fileItem = File::find($file_id);
    if (!$fileItem) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('FileError', 'requested file is invalid!');
    }
    $basePath = public_path('files\\');
    $filePath = $basePath . $fileItem->file_name;
    $currentUserSubscribe = $current_user->currentSubscribe()->first();
    $currentUserSubscribe->increment('subscribe_download_count');
    $fileItem->increment('file_download_num');
    $fileItem->updateDownloadCounts();
    return response()->download($filePath);
}
```

now i'v expected to every download adds 1 number to column `download_count` but 1 filedownload adds 5 and others adds nothing to database!
for example downloading file number 1 for 3 times adds 15 numbers to `Download_count` column!but other files add 1 number to same column or add nothing at all!

I hope you can help me figure this out!

Comment: Internet Download Manager uses multiple treads to download the file, which means, it will be sending multiple requests for different parts of the same file. In your case, it has used 5 threads to download

Comment: @Cerlin OK thanks for your response if I understood well its IDM's tread that causes inserting multiple times in data base...But what is the problem with other files?why my code doesn't work fine?